# Can I play fifa 15 multiplayer with two keyboards from same PC?

Tags: keyboard, fifa-15

I was presented by fifa 15 for PC license.
I want to play it together with my friend. I cannot play joystick.
I want to play using two keyboards from same PC.

Does fifa 15 support following mode?

**P.S.**

Is it possible to play online 2 vs 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Two keyboards would work together, but they shall after that combine into one keyboard (main input),

<kbd>Keyboard 1</kbd> + <kbd>Keyboard 2</kbd> = <kbd>One joint output</kbd>

Meaning you could possibly play one game and split up who wants to play when? But then you could just use one keyboard. If the game does have split screen or two players at once, you shall have to figure out how to separate one keyboard from the other.

Regards

Please note I have never played this game.

Comment: If there are options to set the keys for each player, you should be able to set up two disjunct sets of keys for each player then give both players their own physical keyboards. From the game's perspective it will look as if you were both playing on the same keyboard, but IRL no inconvenience and physical interference.

Comment: Resurrection of an old question! But yes I do not know if you can do that.